# MongoDB group query using PHP driver

Tags: php, mongodb, group-by

I am trying to convert a working `MongoDB` group query into the `PHP` equivalent using the official PHP driver and the group (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.group.php) function.

Here is the **working** raw MongoDB query:

```
db.collection.group(
{
    keyf: function(doc) {
        var date = new Date(doc.executed);
        var dateKey = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
        return {'day': dateKey};
     },
    cond: { executed: { $gt: new Date('01/01/2013') }},
    initial: { executions:0 },
    reduce: function(obj, prev) { prev.executions++; }
});
```

Here is my **not working** PHP code:

```
$keyf = new MongoCode('function(doc) {
    var date = new Date(doc.executed);
    var dateKey = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
    return {\'day\': dateKey};
}');

$initial = array("executions" => 0);
$reduce = "function(obj, prev) { prev.executions++; }";
$conditionals = array("executed" => array('$gt' => "new Date('01/01/2013')"));

$result = $c->group($keyf, $initial, $reduce, array("condition" => $conditionals));
```

And the `print_r()` of `$result`:

```
Array
(
    [retval] => Array
        (
        )

    [count] => 0
    [keys] => 0
    [ok] => 1
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `condition` is comparing a against a string not a date.  You need a [MongoDate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) instead.  Something like:

```
$cond_date = new MongoDate(strtotime("2013-01-01 00:00:00"));
$conditionals = array("executed" => array('$gt' => $cond_date));
```

Comment: Perfect. Anyway I can reverse the sort though, instead of returning `1/30/2013` to `1/1/2013`, I want `1/1/2013` to `1/30/2013`. Thanks.